# mscorlib not found when building Xamarin.Android project with CakeBuild

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, msbuild, cakebuild

I'm in the process of integrating a Xamarin Android project into our CI pipeline. We already use CakeBuild for other .NET projects and so I wanted to use it here, as well.

The problem is that I always get the following error message when trying to build with Cake:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(406,2): error : Could not load assembly
>    'mscorlib, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken='. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile? [C:\[myproject].csproj]

Building works in Visual Studio 2015 and using the Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt. Because of this, I was thinking it had something to do with the environment variables that are set in VS and via the VS command prompt. So what I did was make a small batch file:

```
call "%vs140comntools%vsvars32.bat"
Powershell.exe ./build.ps1 -Target Build
```

But I'm getting the exact same error. In my projects, there is no explicit reference to `mscorlib`.

The Cake build task looks like this:

```
Task("Build")
.IsDependentOn("Restore-NuGet-Packages")
.Does(() =>
{
    var settings = new MSBuildSettings()
    {
        ArgumentCustomization = args =>
        {
            args = args.Append("/t:PackageForAndroid");
            args = args.Append("/p:TargetFrameworkRootPath=\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Reference Assemblies\\Microsoft\\Framework\"");
            return args;
        },
        Verbosity = Verbosity.Normal
    };
    settings.SetConfiguration(configuration);
    MSBuild("../myproject.csproj", settings);    
});
```

I had to add the `TargetFrameworkRootPath` because it won't find the reference assemblies if I do not set it explicitly.

I'm wondering what else to do to replicate the build environment of VS / VS command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Are you targeting .NET Standard or is this still using PCL?
What does the verbose output look like?  It should give you the exact MSBuild command being executed.

`call "%vs140comntools%vsvars32.bat"
Powershell.exe ./build.ps1 -Target Build -Verbosity Diagnostic`